# Связь диагонали экрана и android приложения, как сделать чтобы приложение хорошо смотрелось например на планшетах

Tags: android

Как сделать так, чтобы приложение читалось на планшетах и телефонах с большой и маленькой диагональю?

Comment: эм... например использовать `values-large` папку и так далее.

Comment: @pavel а разве small, large, x-large и прочие не устаревшие?Они используются?

Comment: @Asgard когда они стали устаревшими?

Comment: @Suvitruf да я как то читал, что они больше не используются в альтернативных ресурсах. Так для каких целей они используются например, могли бы написать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cоздавайте layout для разный разрешений экранов вот пример из [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

- res/layout/my_layout.xml
- res/layout-large/my_layout.xml
- res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml
- res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml

Для изображений:

- res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png
- res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png
- res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png
- res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png

Более детально смотрите на [офф. сайте](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).